# Cucumber not showing coloured output in windows

Tags: ruby, windows-7, cucumber, ansicon

this is probably something really stupid but I can't work it out.

I upgraded my version of cucumber to v 0.10.0 and now the test's (running on Win 7) are not showing coloured output with the "pretty" formatter.

When tests are run it prints this error: `*** WARNING: You must use ANSICON 1.31 or higher (http://adoxa.110mb.com/ansicon) to get coloured output on Windows`

I have been to http://adoxa.110mb.com/ansicon but it's not obvious to me how I should be upgrading it. Anyone know how to upgrade my version of anscion?

Comment: You use bundler ? If yes have you add ansicon inside ?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

One of the dev's at my work figured it out.

You need to

1. Download Ansicon from https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon/downloads and unzip it into a directory
   with no spaces
2. Open a command prompt and cd to the folder where you unzipped it
3. Now, cd into either x86 or x64 (depending on your machine’s processor) and install it globally on
   your machine (For example, D:\Cucumber\ansi160\x64)
4. Type `ansicon.exe –i` OR `ansicon -i` and press Enter
5. Any program that prints ANSI colors will now display properly on your machine.

Comment: link doesn't work anymore. it goes to a wordpress template theme site

Comment: Hi guys, the link above no longer works either - can someone upload ansicon to a publicly accessible location?

Comment: I followed the steps exactly, and I get a big error. Running Ruby after installing ansicon always crashes the interpreter. Have to restart my computer and delete the ansicon directory to get Ruby to work again.

Opening debugger in VS: "Unhandled exception at 0x3CC2BE1F in ruby.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x3CC2BE1F."

Comment: @Hoten I am also facing same issue.

Answer (score 5):

Update as of today, http://adoxa.110mb.com/ansicon is no longer accessible.
Files have been uploaded to https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon/downloads.

I tried downloading from adoxa.3eeweb.com, but Chrome warned me that the file was "not commonly downloaded and could be dangerous."

So I opted with the file from github.

Besides that, I just followed the steps mentioned above and my output is now coloured.