# Colorama for Python, Not returning colored print lines on Windows

Tags: python, windows, ansi-escape

I've installed colorama for python. I've imported the module as follows:

```
import colorama
from colorama import init
init()
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style

print Fore.RED + "My Text is Red"
```

and it returns the ANSI charaters....

```
esc[31mMy Text is Red
```

This isn`t what I expected. Am I doing something wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: What operating system are you running this on?

Comment: I`m running windows 7 64 bit....

Comment: Are you running this on the Command Prompt, or in some IDE? It should work in Command Prompt, but not in IDLE or Eclipse Pydev, for example.

Comment: Your code is working just fine for me in `cmd.exe`: Win 7 x64, Python 2.7.6 x64, colorama 0.3.1

Comment: Yep, should work. On `cmd` it works for me, as well as Cygwin. (Windows 10, Python35)

Answer (score 52):

I had this same issue on Windows 7 x64, I finally got the colors working without having to install anything new just by adding the argument `convert=True` to the init call.

```
from colorama import init, Fore, Back, Style

init(convert=True)

print(Fore.RED + 'some red text')
```

Comment: I use it on Windows 10,but it doesn't work. It doesn't show the color

Comment: I used it on windows 10 and it works in my case but when running python from cmd

Comment: Hey, so I know this method but it won't always work. Like suddenly, inside functions it stops printing colored text. Furthermore, even if I add the `init(convert=True)` para inside the function or anything, it won't work. For me it just works like in the starting 100 lines of code. I don't know why. Maybe if someone could help :) *Edit: I'm late on this though, but I'd be grateful cause this is a problem I'm facing since months!*

Answer (score 8):

I've never had success getting colors working in Windows cmd.exe without patching it with Ansicon.  After patching, ANSI color codes will work without needing to use something like colorama (which didn't work for me either).

To patch cmd.exe with Ansicon, do the following:

1. Download Ansicon from https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon/downloads and unzip it into a directory with no spaces
2. Use a cmd prompt and navigate to where you unzipped it.
3. CD into the x64 directory (unless you have a 32bit machine, then use the x86 one)
4. Type `ansicon.exe –i`
5. Open a new cmd prompt

via: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4749307/191902

Also, if you have an NVidia graphics card, you might need to set the environment variable "ANSICON_EXC" to "nvd3d9wrap.dll"﻿.

Comment: ansicon -i makes it work on all my cmd.exe shells. However, the Python command line shell still won't interpret the escape sequences. \x1b in front of valid ANSI sequences still shows as a left pointing arrow. Is there anything else I must do?

Answer (score 5):

I realise this is a very old question, but none of the existing answers helped me, so I'm posting my solution in case others are in the same boat. In my case, the problem was that I was importing `stdout` from `sys` and then initialising `colorama`, which does not work:

```
>>> from colorama import Fore, Style, init
>>> from sys import stdout
>>> init()
>>> stdout.write(Fore.RED + Style.BRIGHT + "Test" + Style.RESET_ALL + "\n")
[31m[1mTest[0m
```

Per https://pypi.org/project/colorama, this is because:

> On Windows, colorama works by replacing `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr` with proxy objects, which override the `.write()` method to do their work.

Thus, I need to import `stdout` *after* it has been replaced as part of the call to `init`:

```
>>> from colorama import Fore, Style, init
>>> init()
>>> from sys import stdout
>>> stdout.write(Fore.RED + Style.BRIGHT + "Test" + Style.RESET_ALL + "\n")
Test      <--- This is now bright red.
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks a lot for this info! now it works just fine even on Windows 10!

Answer (score 4):

I know I'm late, but this will hopefully help anyone still looking for the answer.

Stating from [Colorama's documentation on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/colorama/):

> Colorama can be used happily in conjunction with existing ANSI libraries such as Termcolor
>
> ```
> from colorama import init
> from termcolor import colored
>
> # use Colorama to make Termcolor work on Windows too
> init()
>
> # then use Termcolor for all colored text output
> print(colored('Hello, World!', 'green', 'on_red'))
> ```

This worked for me, on Anaconda Prompt (essentially `cmd.exe`) on Windows 10 64-bit.

Colorama's native ANSI sequences don't seem to work for some reason. An external ANSI library (i.e. Termcolor) did the trick for me.

Answer (score 3):

hi before printing clear cmd

```py
import os
from colorama import init,Fore
init()
os.system("cls" or "clear")

print Fore.RED + "My Text is Red"
```

Comment: Can you please add a code that successfully runs with an explanation of the same? It seems you are using "Fore" from Colorama without importing it.

Answer (score 1):

That's normal because you do not have `ANSI` on Windows.

Try somehting like [tendo.colorer](https://github.com/ssbarnea/tendo/blob/master/tendo/colorer.py) and this will enable coloring for all platforms.

Note: tendo.colorer adds coloring to the logs, but I'm sure you will figure it out on how to use it for other things. If I'm not mistaking just importing it before your code it will fix the problem.

Comment: You're missing the point. OP explicitly states that he already has the [colorama](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama) library.

Comment: @Junuxx, maybe so, but if it what the OP wants to do doesn't work, alternatives should be suggested.  I was having this issue with colorama not working on Windows.  The tendo.colorer module worked for me.  Though the URL is now https://github.com/pycontribs/tendo/blob/master/tendo/colorer.py

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but I'll answer for any new people visiting. Pretty much what worked for me was putting a console clear command before printing my colored text.

For example, instead of doing this:

```
#random code above
def print_string():
    print(f'{Fore.YELLOW} Hello World {Fore.RESET}')
```

Do this:

```
#random code above
def print_string():
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear') # multi-platform clear statement
    print(f'{Fore.YELLOW} Hello World {Fore.RESET}')
```

I have no idea how it works, but clearing the console in certain areas seems to fix your issue. I had this as well and a friend recommended to do this and it worked. Hope this helped.

(This fixes problems with ANSI Escape Codes too, as well as colorama.)

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
colorama.init()
```

Or

```
from colorama import init
init()
```

To Your Code And It Will Work

Answer (score 0):

just paste this at end of imports Ez

```
init(convert=True)
os.system("mode 360")
os.system("cls")
```

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the answer. It would really help our readers if you could explain why and how your answer solves the OPs problems

Answer (score -3):

you can use the import only one import. such as:

```
from colorama import init, Fore, Back, Style

init()
```

and you can try it now :

```
print(Fore.RED + 'some red text')
print(Back.GREEN + 'and with a green background')
print(Style.DIM + 'and in dim text')
print(Fore.RESET + Back.RESET + Style.RESET_ALL)
```

Answer (score -6):

Try The following:

```
import colorama

colorama.init()
print colorama.Fore.GREEN + " Hey, im green! "
```

Comment: This is no different than the example in the question, just using superficially different import syntax.

Comment: Same thing as the question.