# logger configuration to log to file and print to stdout

Tags: python, file, logging, stdout, python-logging

I'm using Python's logging module to log some debug strings to a file which works pretty well. Now in addition, I'd like to use this module to also print the strings out to stdout. How do I do this? In order to log my strings to a file I use following code:

```
import logging
import logging.handlers
logger = logging.getLogger("")
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(
    LOGFILE, maxBytes=(1048576*5), backupCount=7
)
formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s")
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)
```

and then call a logger function like

```
logger.debug("I am written to the file")
```

Thank you for some help here!

Comment: curious, if you change the level to `DEBUG` does it still log to stdout AND the file? I think it's only if its set to `INFO`. Correct me if I'm wrong please.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14058453

Answer (score 739, accepted):

Just get a handle to the root logger and add the `StreamHandler`. The `StreamHandler` writes to stderr. Not sure if you really need stdout over stderr, but this is what I use when I setup the Python logger and I also add the `FileHandler` as well. Then all my logs go to both places (which is what it sounds like you want).

```
import logging
logging.getLogger().addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
```

If you want to output to `stdout` instead of `stderr`, you just need to specify it to the `StreamHandler` constructor.

```
import sys
# ...
logging.getLogger().addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout))
```

You could also add a `Formatter` to it so all your log lines have a common header.

ie:

```
import logging
logFormatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s [%(threadName)-12.12s] [%(levelname)-5.5s]  %(message)s")
rootLogger = logging.getLogger()

fileHandler = logging.FileHandler("{0}/{1}.log".format(logPath, fileName))
fileHandler.setFormatter(logFormatter)
rootLogger.addHandler(fileHandler)

consoleHandler = logging.StreamHandler()
consoleHandler.setFormatter(logFormatter)
rootLogger.addHandler(consoleHandler)
```

Prints to the format of:

```
2012-12-05 16:58:26,618 [MainThread  ] [INFO ]  my message
```

Comment: You could also just initialize the `StreamHandler` with `sys.stdout`, and then it will log to that instead of stderr.

Comment: @sr2222 logger.addHandler(sys.stdout) gives me NameError: name 'sys' is not defined

Comment: Well yeah... you have to `import sys` first.  And actually initialize the handler, ie `consoleHandler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)`

Comment: @sr2222 This doesn't seem to work for me, I start getting seemingly unrelated errors once i include a "logger.addHandler(sys.stdout)"

Comment: Because as I already said, that's not how you do it.  Create the HANDLER with sys.stdout, then attach the handler to the logger.

Comment: Don't forget the ```rootLogger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)``` if you are trying to see info or debug messages

Comment: Is it possible to set different log levels on the two handlers?

Comment: Curious,  would I prefer this answer vs this one that looks simpler: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46098711/1601580 ?

Comment: curious, if you change the level to `DEBUG` does it still log to stdout AND the file? I think it's only if its set to `INFO`. Correct me if I'm wrong please.

Comment: Problem: if you do this, this will **only** apply to the current module's `logger = logging.getLogger()`, and you have to redo this for all submodules. For this reason, @Yirkha's solution might be better.

Comment: logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout) did the eventual trick.

Answer (score 663):

[`logging.basicConfig()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig) can take a keyword argument `handlers` since Python 3.3, which simplifies logging setup a lot, especially when setting up multiple handlers with the same formatter:

> **`handlers`** – If specified, this should be an iterable of already created handlers to add to the root logger. Any handlers which don’t already have a formatter set will be assigned the default formatter created in this function.

The whole setup can therefore be done with a single call like this:

```py
import logging

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO,
    format="%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(message)s",
    handlers=[
        logging.FileHandler("debug.log"),
        logging.StreamHandler()
    ]
)
```

(Or with `import sys` + `StreamHandler(sys.stdout)` per original question's requirements – the default for StreamHandler is to write to stderr. Look at [LogRecord attributes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes) if you want to customize the log format and add things like filename/line, thread info etc.)

The setup above needs to be done only once near the beginning of the script. You can use the logging from all other places in the codebase later like this:

```py
logging.info('Useful message')
logging.error('Something bad happened')
...
```

Note: If it doesn't work, someone else has probably already initialized the logging system differently. Comments suggest doing `logging.root.handlers = []` before the call to `basicConfig()`.

Comment: don't forget to set level=logging.INFO or the desired level as well

Comment: Definition for `FileHandler`: `logging.FileHandler(filename, mode='a', encoding=None, delay=False)`. This means, that when you just want to log in the same folder, you can just use `FileHandler("mylog.log")`. If you want to overwrite the log each time, set "w" as the second argument.

Comment: I tried this, but the output file is empty although the console is giving the output.. Any suggestions..?

Comment: @Ramesh-X , this drove me crazy as well. just do `logging.root.handlers = []` before the call to `basicConfig`, take a look at the function - it's annoying.

Comment: I also need `noinspection PyArgumentList` to make PyCharm happy, due to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-39762

Comment: This has proven dangerous for me, as it often results in crashes.  Be warned, if you turn on logging by directly using the logging object, you have no idea how munch log output might be generated from within the packages or directories you are using.

Comment: curious, if you change the level to `DEBUG` does it still log to stdout AND the file? I think it's only if its set to `INFO`. Correct me if I'm wrong please. Thanks for the answer +1 for simplicity and clarity.

Comment: @CharlieParker Seems to be working as expected for me, e.g. https://www.online-python.com/J18TSc35Gp If it does not for you, I suspect something is messing with the logging system elsewhere in the program. If more complex, consider posting a new separate question

Comment: @Yirkha : How can I add rotating file handler in this?

Comment: @HarshaBiyani `handlers = [ logging.RotatingFileHandler("filename.log") ... ` instead of the `FileHandler`, or whatever other handler you want to use from https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html

Answer (score 91):

Adding a StreamHandler without arguments goes to stderr instead of stdout. If some other process has a dependency on the stdout dump (i.e. when writing an NRPE plugin), then make sure to specify stdout explicitly or you might run into some unexpected troubles.

Here's a quick example reusing the assumed values and LOGFILE from the question:

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
from logging import handlers
import sys

log = logging.getLogger('')
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
format = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s")

ch = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
ch.setFormatter(format)
log.addHandler(ch)

fh = handlers.RotatingFileHandler(LOGFILE, maxBytes=(1048576*5), backupCount=7)
fh.setFormatter(format)
log.addHandler(fh)
```

Comment: curious, if you change the level to `DEBUG` does it still log to stdout AND the file? I think it's only if its set to `INFO`. Correct me if I'm wrong please.

Answer (score 33):

Here is a complete, nicely wrapped solution based on [Waterboy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13733863/1976617) and various other sources. It supports logging to both console and log file, allows for different log level settings, provides colorized output and is easily configurable (also available as [Gist](https://gist.github.com/fonic/7e5ab76d951a2ab2d5f526a7db3e2004)):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#                                                                               -
#  Python dual-logging setup (console and log file),                            -
#  supporting different log levels and colorized output                         -
#                                                                               -
#  Created by Fonic <https://github.com/fonic>                                  -
#  Date: 04/05/20 - 02/07/23                                                    -
#                                                                               -
#  Based on:                                                                    -
#  https://stackoverflow.com/a/13733863/1976617                                 -
#  https://uran198.github.io/en/python/2016/07/12/colorful-python-logging.html  -
#  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors                        -
#                                                                               -
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Imports
import os
import sys
import logging

# Logging formatter supporting colorized output
class LogFormatter(logging.Formatter):

    COLOR_CODES = {
        logging.CRITICAL: "\033[1;35m", # bright/bold magenta
        logging.ERROR:    "\033[1;31m", # bright/bold red
        logging.WARNING:  "\033[1;33m", # bright/bold yellow
        logging.INFO:     "\033[0;37m", # white / light gray
        logging.DEBUG:    "\033[1;30m"  # bright/bold black / dark gray
    }

    RESET_CODE = "\033[0m"

    def __init__(self, color, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LogFormatter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.color = color

    def format(self, record, *args, **kwargs):
        if (self.color == True and record.levelno in self.COLOR_CODES):
            record.color_on  = self.COLOR_CODES[record.levelno]
            record.color_off = self.RESET_CODE
        else:
            record.color_on  = ""
            record.color_off = ""
        return super(LogFormatter, self).format(record, *args, **kwargs)

# Set up logging
def set_up_logging(console_log_output, console_log_level, console_log_color, logfile_file, logfile_log_level, logfile_log_color, log_line_template):

    # Create logger
    # For simplicity, we use the root logger, i.e. call 'logging.getLogger()'
    # without name argument. This way we can simply use module methods for
    # for logging throughout the script. An alternative would be exporting
    # the logger, i.e. 'global logger; logger = logging.getLogger("<name>")'
    logger = logging.getLogger()

    # Set global log level to 'debug' (required for handler levels to work)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    # Create console handler
    console_log_output = console_log_output.lower()
    if (console_log_output == "stdout"):
        console_log_output = sys.stdout
    elif (console_log_output == "stderr"):
        console_log_output = sys.stderr
    else:
        print("Failed to set console output: invalid output: '%s'" % console_log_output)
        return False
    console_handler = logging.StreamHandler(console_log_output)

    # Set console log level
    try:
        console_handler.setLevel(console_log_level.upper()) # only accepts uppercase level names
    except:
        print("Failed to set console log level: invalid level: '%s'" % console_log_level)
        return False

    # Create and set formatter, add console handler to logger
    console_formatter = LogFormatter(fmt=log_line_template, color=console_log_color)
    console_handler.setFormatter(console_formatter)
    logger.addHandler(console_handler)

    # Create log file handler
    try:
        logfile_handler = logging.FileHandler(logfile_file)
    except Exception as exception:
        print("Failed to set up log file: %s" % str(exception))
        return False

    # Set log file log level
    try:
        logfile_handler.setLevel(logfile_log_level.upper()) # only accepts uppercase level names
    except:
        print("Failed to set log file log level: invalid level: '%s'" % logfile_log_level)
        return False

    # Create and set formatter, add log file handler to logger
    logfile_formatter = LogFormatter(fmt=log_line_template, color=logfile_log_color)
    logfile_handler.setFormatter(logfile_formatter)
    logger.addHandler(logfile_handler)

    # Success
    return True

# Main function
def main():

    # Set up logging
    script_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(sys.argv[0]))[0]
    if (not set_up_logging(console_log_output="stdout", console_log_level="warning", console_log_color=True,
                           logfile_file=script_name + ".log", logfile_log_level="debug", logfile_log_color=False,
                           log_line_template="%(color_on)s[%(created)d] [%(threadName)s] [%(levelname)-8s] %(message)s%(color_off)s")):
        print("Failed to set up logging, aborting.")
        return 1

    # Log some messages
    logging.debug("Debug message")
    logging.info("Info message")
    logging.warning("Warning message")
    logging.error("Error message")
    logging.critical("Critical message")

# Call main function
if (__name__ == "__main__"):
    sys.exit(main())
```

---

**NOTE regarding Microsoft Windows:**
For colorized output to work within the classic *Command Prompt* of *Microsoft Windows*, some additional code is necessary. This does NOT apply to the newer [*Terminal*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/) app which supports colorized output out of the box.

There are two options:

**1)** Use Python package [colorama](https://pypi.org/project/colorama/) (filters output sent to *stdout* and *stderr* and translates escape sequences to native Windows API calls; works on Windows XP and later):

```
import colorama
colorama.init()
```

**2)** Enable ANSI terminal mode using the following function (enables terminal to interpret escape sequences by setting flag `ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING`; more info on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36760881/1976617), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37505496/1976617), [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolemode) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences); works on Windows 10 and later):

```
# Imports
import sys
import ctypes

# Enable ANSI terminal mode for Command Prompt on Microsoft Windows
def windows_enable_ansi_terminal_mode():
    if (sys.platform != "win32"):
        return None
    try:
        kernel32 = ctypes.windll.kernel32
        result = kernel32.SetConsoleMode(kernel32.GetStdHandle(-11), 7)
        if (result == 0): raise Exception
        return True
    except:
        return False
```

Comment: In windows terminal the colors don't appear with this code. If you want them to appear in windows terminal just "import colorama".

Comment: @bitfhacker: yes, but that is not related to my code. On Windows 10, you have to enabled ANSI terminal mode first. Sadly, Python itself doesn't do it when it starts. I added a function to enable it that I have been using successfully for a while now.

Comment: This worked for me on Win10: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9848889/colorama-for-python-not-returning-colored-print-lines-on-windows#answer-40424449
--> "from colorama import init" and with "init(convert=True)"  in the following line after "LogFormatter(loggin.Formatter):"

Comment: @Maxxim do you know how this would work across multiple files? I initiate the logger in main.py and then use logging.debug etc. in other files which does not seem to work

Comment: @Björn It should work exactly like you described. I do the same in my projects: set up logging once in `main.py`, then `import logging` + `logging.debug()` etc. in modules. Not really sure why it is not working in your case.

Comment: I really have no idea why it is not working. It creates the .log file but in the other files, it just writes to the console instead of the file :(

Comment: Do I have to import logging in the other files as well? I think that is what is going wrong on my end. Or do I have to import some logger variable from main?

Comment: @Björn you have to `import logging` in other files as well, yes. You don't need to import any logger variables from `main.py`

Answer (score 19):

Either run `basicConfig` with `stream=sys.stdout` as the argument prior to setting up any other handlers or logging any messages, or manually add a `StreamHandler` that pushes messages to stdout to the root logger (or any other logger you want, for that matter).

Comment: I get an error when I try to use `stream` and `filename` arguments together or with a handler

Answer (score 15):

Logging to `stdout` and `rotating file` with different levels and formats:

```
import logging
import logging.handlers
import sys
    
if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Change root logger level from WARNING (default) to NOTSET in order for all messages to be delegated.
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.NOTSET)

    # Add stdout handler, with level INFO
    console = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
    console.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(name)-13s: %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
    console.setFormatter(formatter)
    logging.getLogger().addHandler(console)

    # Add file rotating handler, with level DEBUG
    rotatingHandler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(filename='rotating.log', maxBytes=1000, backupCount=5)
    rotatingHandler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    rotatingHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logging.getLogger().addHandler(rotatingHandler)

    log = logging.getLogger("app." + __name__)
    
    log.debug('Debug message, should only appear in the file.')
    log.info('Info message, should appear in file and stdout.')
    log.warning('Warning message, should appear in file and stdout.')
    log.error('Error message, should appear in file and stdout.')
```

Comment: Getting `ValueError: unsupported format character 'n' (0x6e) at index 46` when used `\n` and `%s` in the log message

Answer (score 7):

After having used Waterboy's code over and over in multiple Python packages, I finally cast it into a tiny standalone Python package, which you can find here:

https://github.com/acschaefer/duallog

The code is well documented and easy to use. Simply download the `.py` file and include it in your project, or install the whole package via `pip install duallog`.

Comment: For some reason is not getting logged to the console neither file (is empty)

Answer (score 1):

Although the question specifically asks for a *logger configuration*, there *is* an alternative approach that does not require any changes to the `logging` configuration, nor does it require redirecting `stdout`.

A bit simplistic, perhaps, but it works:

```py
def log_and_print(message: str, level: int, logger: logging.Logger):
    logger.log(level=level, msg=message)  # log as normal
    print(message)  # prints to stdout by default
```

Instead of e.g. `logger.debug('something')` we now call `log_and_print(message='something', level=logging.DEBUG, logger=logger)`.

We can also expand this a little, so it [print](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print)s to `stdout` only when necessary:

```py
def log_print(message: str, level: int, logger: logging.Logger):
    # log the message normally
    logger.log(level=level, msg=message)
    # only print to stdout if the message is not logged to stdout
    msg_logged_to_stdout = False
    current_logger = logger
    while current_logger and not msg_logged_to_stdout:
        is_enabled = current_logger.isEnabledFor(level)
        logs_to_stdout = any(
            getattr(handler, 'stream', None) == sys.stdout
            for handler in current_logger.handlers
        )
        msg_logged_to_stdout = is_enabled and logs_to_stdout
        if not current_logger.propagate:
            current_logger = None
        else:
            current_logger = current_logger.parent            
    if not msg_logged_to_stdout:
        print(message)
```

This checks the logger and its parents for any handlers that stream to `stdout`, and checks if the logger is enabled for the specified level.

Note this has *not* been [optimized](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#optimization) for performance.

Answer (score 0):

I have handled redirecting logs and prints to a file on disk, stdout, and stderr simultaneously, via the following module (the [Gist is also available here](https://gist.github.com/SHi-ON/606e2f523045766b6771ceca45968d8b)):

```
import logging
import pathlib
import sys

from ml.common.const import LOG_DIR_PATH, ML_DIR


def create_log_file_path(file_path, root_dir=ML_DIR, log_dir=LOG_DIR_PATH):
    path_parts = list(pathlib.Path(file_path).parts)
    relative_path_parts = path_parts[path_parts.index(root_dir) + 1:]
    log_file_path = pathlib.Path(log_dir, *relative_path_parts)
    log_file_path = log_file_path.with_suffix('.log')
    # Create the directories and the file itself
    log_file_path.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    log_file_path.touch(exist_ok=True)
    return log_file_path


def set_up_logs(file_path, mode='a', level=logging.INFO):
    log_file_path = create_log_file_path(file_path)
    logging_handlers = [logging.FileHandler(log_file_path, mode=mode),
                        logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)]
    logging.basicConfig(
        handlers=logging_handlers,
        format='%(asctime)s %(name)s %(levelname)s %(message)s',
        level=level
    )


class OpenedFileHandler(logging.FileHandler):

    def __init__(self, file_handle, filename, mode):
        self.file_handle = file_handle
        super(OpenedFileHandler, self).__init__(filename, mode)

    def _open(self):
        return self.file_handle


class StandardError:
    def __init__(self, buffer_stderr, buffer_file):
        self.buffer_stderr = buffer_stderr
        self.buffer_file = buffer_file

    def write(self, message):
        self.buffer_stderr.write(message)
        self.buffer_file.write(message)


class StandardOutput:
    def __init__(self, buffer_stdout, buffer_file):
        self.buffer_stdout = buffer_stdout
        self.buffer_file = buffer_file

    def write(self, message):
        self.buffer_stdout.write(message)
        self.buffer_file.write(message)


class Logger:
    def __init__(self, file_path, mode='a', level=logging.INFO):
        self.stdout_ = sys.stdout
        self.stderr_ = sys.stderr

        log_file_path = create_log_file_path(file_path)
        self.file_ = open(log_file_path, mode=mode)

        logging_handlers = [OpenedFileHandler(self.file_, log_file_path,
                                              mode=mode),
                            logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)]
        logging.basicConfig(
            handlers=logging_handlers,
            format='%(asctime)s %(name)s %(levelname)s %(message)s',
            level=level
        )

    # Overrides write() method of stdout and stderr buffers
    def write(self, message):
        self.stdout_.write(message)
        self.stderr_.write(message)
        self.file_.write(message)

    def flush(self):
        pass

    def __enter__(self):
        sys.stdout = StandardOutput(self.stdout_, self.file_)
        sys.stderr = StandardError(self.stderr_, self.file_)

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        sys.stdout = self.stdout_
        sys.stderr = self.stderr_
        self.file_.close()
```

Written as a context manager, you can simply add the functionality to your python script by adding an extra line:

```
from logger import Logger

...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Logger(__file__):
        main()
```