# Redirecting stdout, stderror to file while stderr still prints to screen

Tags: python, redirect, stderr

I would like stdout and stderr to be redirected to the same file, while stderr still writes to the screen. What's the most pythonic way to do this?

Comment: You mean within the current program, or for a subprocess?

Comment: @abarnert yes, the current program, not a subprocess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to redirect the current script's stdout and stderr, not some subprocess you're running.

This doesn't sound like a very Pythonic thing to do in the first place, but if you need to, the Pythonic solution would be:

- Redirect `stdout` to a file.
- Redirect `stderr` to a custom file-like object that writes to the file and also writes to the real `stderr`.

Something like this:

```
class Tee(object):
    def __init__(self, f1, f2):
        self.f1, self.f2 = f1, f2
    def write(self, msg):
        self.f1.write(msg)
        self.f2.write(msg)

outfile = open('outfile', 'w')

sys.stdout = outfile
sys.stderr = Tee(sys.stderr, outfile)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to [use the python logging framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733552/logger-configuration-to-log-to-file-and-print-to-stdout) to send your messages to both places, instead of actually redirecting stdout / stderr.  As a less-pythonic alternative, [you could make a custom file-like object that's write method will write to both `sys.__stdout__` and your file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796492/python-temporarily-redirect-stdout-stderr), and assign sys.stdout to your custom object. You would then do the same for stderr.  Please see the [documentation for the sys module](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/sys.html#sys.stdin)

Comment: No, you still have `stderr` to write to the screen. (Not to mention `sys.__stdout__` and `sys.__stderr__`.) and of course you can always save the original `stdout` before redirecting it.

Comment: He wants to redirect stderr as well.  You're right about sys.stdout vs sys.__stdout__, I'll update my answer to include that

Comment: Yes, he wants to redirect stderr so that it writes to a file and to real `stderr`. And there's absolutely nothing stopping him from doing so; I don't know why you think this will be a problem. Meanwhile, he doesn't want `stdout` to go to the screen, just to a file, so why are you explaining how to do that?