# python - print to stdout and redirect output to file

Tags: python, redirect, stdout

I can run my python scripts on the terminal and get the print results on the *stdout* e.g.

`python myprog.py`

or simply redirect it to a file:

`python myprog.py > out.txt`

My question is how could I do both solutions at the same time.
My linux experience will tell me something like:

`python myprog.py |& tee out.txt`

This is not having the behaviour I expected, print on the fly and not all at once when the program ends.

So what I wanted (preferred without changing python code) is the same behavior as `python myprog.py` (print on the fly) but also redirecting output to a file.

What is the simplest way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use 'tee'. `stdbuf -oL python mycode.py | tee out.txt`

Comment: I tried that as mentioned. this only puts the results on the stdout when the script finishes, I'd like to have stdout updated on the fly!

Comment: Try placing stdbuf -oL in front of python like in my update. See the man page for explanation http://linux.die.net/man/1/stdbuf

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party (my last answer was bad), but you could look into the `logging` library. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/logging.html) for a more ample documentation, but the gist of it is to use two outputs for the logging library. A similar question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733552/logger-configuration-to-log-to-file-and-print-to-stdout).