# How to enable Windows console QuickEdit Mode from python?

Tags: python, windows, console, prompt

I'd like to force QuickEdit Mode in the console when running a python script and then disable it right before terminating. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Here's a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76855923/15016163

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) to call [`GetConsoleMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683167) and [`SetConsoleMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686033).

ctypes definitions:

```
import msvcrt
import atexit
import ctypes
from ctypes import wintypes

kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True)

# input flags
ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT = 0x0001
ENABLE_LINE_INPUT      = 0x0002
ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT      = 0x0004
ENABLE_WINDOW_INPUT    = 0x0008
ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT     = 0x0010
ENABLE_INSERT_MODE     = 0x0020
ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT_MODE = 0x0040
ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS  = 0x0080

# output flags
ENABLE_PROCESSED_OUTPUT   = 0x0001
ENABLE_WRAP_AT_EOL_OUTPUT = 0x0002
ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING = 0x0004 # VT100 (Win 10)

def check_zero(result, func, args):    
    if not result:
        err = ctypes.get_last_error()
        if err:
            raise ctypes.WinError(err)
    return args

if not hasattr(wintypes, 'LPDWORD'): # PY2
    wintypes.LPDWORD = ctypes.POINTER(wintypes.DWORD)

kernel32.GetConsoleMode.errcheck= check_zero
kernel32.GetConsoleMode.argtypes = (
    wintypes.HANDLE,   # _In_  hConsoleHandle
    wintypes.LPDWORD,) # _Out_ lpMode

kernel32.SetConsoleMode.errcheck= check_zero
kernel32.SetConsoleMode.argtypes = (
    wintypes.HANDLE, # _In_  hConsoleHandle
    wintypes.DWORD,) # _Out_ lpMode
```

The following wraps the underlying WinAPI functions as `get_console_mode` and `set_console_mode`. I've limited the wrappers to operating on just the console's active input buffer or active output buffer, i.e. `\\.\CONIN$` and `\\.\CONOUT$`. I think this is simpler than having to worry about file descriptors and handles. Notably `sys.stdin` and `sys.stdout` may be redirected elsewhere, as may also be the case for the C runtime's standard I/O `FILE` streams, file descriptors, and the Windows standard handles that you can get from `GetStdHandle`. In these cases you can still open `CONIN$` and `CONOUT$`, as long as the process is attached to a console.

```
def get_console_mode(output=False):
    '''Get the mode of the active console input or output
       buffer. Note that if the process isn't attached to a
       console, this function raises an EBADF IOError.
    '''
    device = r'\\.\CONOUT$' if output else r'\\.\CONIN$'
    with open(device, 'r+') as con:
        mode = wintypes.DWORD()
        hCon = msvcrt.get_osfhandle(con.fileno())
        kernel32.GetConsoleMode(hCon, ctypes.byref(mode))
        return mode.value

def set_console_mode(mode, output=False):
    '''Set the mode of the active console input or output
       buffer. Note that if the process isn't attached to a
       console, this function raises an EBADF IOError.
    '''
    device = r'\\.\CONOUT$' if output else r'\\.\CONIN$'
    with open(device, 'r+') as con:
        hCon = msvcrt.get_osfhandle(con.fileno())
        kernel32.SetConsoleMode(hCon, mode)
```

`update_console_mode` combines the latter functions to let you pass in the `flags` you want to set and the `mask` of flags to modify. This includes flags to clear. It also allows restoring the previous mode by registering an [atexit function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html#atexit.register).

```
def update_console_mode(flags, mask, output=False, restore=False):
    '''Update a masked subset of the current mode of the active
       console input or output buffer. Note that if the process
       isn't attached to a console, this function raises an
       EBADF IOError.
    '''
    current_mode = get_console_mode(output)
    if current_mode & mask != flags & mask:
        mode = current_mode & ~mask | flags & mask
        set_console_mode(mode, output)
    else:
        restore = False
    if restore:
        atexit.register(set_console_mode, current_mode, output)
```

Example:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import os
    import sys
    import time

    if sys.stderr is None:
        os.close(2)
        sys.stderr = open('stderr.txt', 'w', buffering=1)

    print("%#06x, %#06x" % (get_console_mode(),
                            get_console_mode(output=True)))    

    flags = mask = ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS | ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT_MODE
    update_console_mode(flags, mask, restore=True)

    print("%#06x, %#06x" % (get_console_mode(),
                            get_console_mode(output=True)))    

    time.sleep(10) # check console properties
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll give that a try.

Comment: I had to open CONIN$ with mode `r` rather than `r+`, otherwise I got the exception `File or stream is not seekable`, using the new Windows 10 console.

Comment: I should also note that, per the [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolemode), you also need to have set ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS to enable or disable quick edit mode. This tripped me up when I tried to do this in a PowerShell window.

Answer (score 8):

for anyone trying to disable the QuickEdit and Insert mode for the current console only and is unable to find a simple solution:

```py
import ctypes

kernel32 = ctypes.windll.kernel32
kernel32.SetConsoleMode(kernel32.GetStdHandle(-10), 128)
```

Comment: Worked right out of the box like a dream and allowed me to end my work day on a high note. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This might be helpful to anyone trying to enable and disable only quick edit mode in Windows without disabling other features.

```python
def quickedit(enabled=1): # This is a patch to the system that sometimes hangs
        import ctypes
        '''
        Enable or disable quick edit mode to prevent system hangs, sometimes when using remote desktop
        Param (Enabled)
        enabled = 1(default), enable quick edit mode in python console
        enabled = 0, disable quick edit mode in python console
        '''
        # -10 is input handle => STD_INPUT_HANDLE (DWORD) -10 | https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getstdhandle
        # default = (0x4|0x80|0x20|0x2|0x10|0x1|0x40|0x200)
        # 0x40 is quick edit, #0x20 is insert mode
        # 0x8 is disabled by default
        # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolemode
        kernel32 = ctypes.windll.kernel32
        if enabled:
            kernel32.SetConsoleMode(kernel32.GetStdHandle(-10), (0x4|0x80|0x20|0x2|0x10|0x1|0x40|0x100))
            print("Console Quick Edit Enabled")
        else:
            kernel32.SetConsoleMode(kernel32.GetStdHandle(-10), (0x4|0x80|0x20|0x2|0x10|0x1|0x00|0x100))
            print("Console Quick Edit Disabled")

quickedit(0) # Disable quick edit in terminal
```

Just disable the 0x40 flag which is quick edit