# Python: Logging actions and exceptions with time stamp

Tags: python, logging, error-logging

I am writing a script that connects to N hosts via SSH ... queries the 3rd party system and extracts data and then displays all the collected data in a certain format.

I want to log all the actions the script is executing as well as any exceptions encountered on to the console and to a log file, so that the user can see what is happening while the script is running (If someone used Ansible - then just like the output we get on the console and logs when running the playbooks)

Expected output

- [timestamp]: connecting machine 1
- [timestamp]: connection established
- [timestamp]: querying database xyz
- [timestamp]: ERR: invalid credentials
- [timestamp]: aborting data extraction
- [timestamp]: connection closed
- [timestamp]: ---------------------------
- [timestamp]: connecting machine 2
- [timestamp]: connection established
- [timestamp]: querying database xyz
- [timestamp]: extraction complete
- [timestamp]: closing the connection

I hope I am able to explain it correctly - Logging actions and exceptions with timestamp for the whole script and all the data iterations.

Please advice and if possible with an example script that uses the technique. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can have a look [here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/logging.html) for some more detailed guidance. Here's how I usually set up logging on my stuff:

```
import logging

...

logger = logging.getLogger()
log_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
log_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s - %(funcName)s - line %(lineno)d"))
log_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(log_handler)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

This will produce output like this, for any event from `DEBUG` upwards:

```
2017-05-16 13:30:03,193 - root - INFO - Starting execution - main - line 35
2017-05-16 13:30:03,206 - root - DEBUG - Config file grabbed successfully - readConfig - line 71
...
2017-05-15 13:30:26,792 - root - WARNING - Reached maximum number of attempts (3) for this request; skipping request. - main - line 79
2017-05-15 13:30:26,797 - root - ERROR - Failed to grab item. Unfortunately, this is a showstopper :( - main - line 79
```

The above is produced by a line in the `main` function of my app, that reads:

```
logger.info("Starting execution")
```

Another line in my `readConfig` function:

```
logging.debug("Config file grabbed successfully")
```

And another two lines in `main` again:

```
logging.warning("Reached maximum number of attempts ({max_attempts}) for this request; skipping request.".format(max_attempts = max_tries))
...
logging.error("Failed to grab item. Unfortunately, this is a showstopper :(")
```

Then it's a matter of how much information and context you need on each log entry. Have a look [here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/logging.html#changing-the-format-of-displayed-messages) at formatting the entries, and [here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/logging.html#formatters) at formatters. I'll have these sent to me via email, anytime the app runs triggered by `crontab`, by adding `MAILTO = root` to the top of my `crontab` file, [and making sure my system email is properly set](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26980).

If you want to set it to go to the console *and* a file, you'll just need to set two different handlers. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13733863/7968653) provides a good example, where you'd set [a `StreamHandler`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/logging.handlers.html#streamhandler) to log to the console, and [a `FileHandler`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/logging.handlers.html#filehandler) to log to a file. So instead of setting it up as I mentioned above I usually do, you could try:

```
import logging

...

# Set up logging and formatting
logger = logging.getLogger()
logFormatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s - %(funcName)s - line %(lineno)d")

# Set up the console handler
consoleHandler = logging.StreamHandler()
consoleHandler.setFormatter(logFormatter)
logger.addHandler(consoleHandler)

# Set up the file handler 
fileHandler = logging.FileHandler("{0}/{1}.log".format(logPath, fileName))
fileHandler.setFormatter(logFormatter)
logger.addHandler(fileHandler)

# Set up logging levels
consoleHandler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
fileHandler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Comment: Thanks I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the **logging** module [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial), there's a nice example section with both basic and advanced applications.  Doing stuff in the format you've described appears to be included in the tutorial.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into it