# python logging prints to file but nothing to console

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

[logger configuration to log to file and print to stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733552/logger-configuration-to-log-to-file-and-print-to-stdout) would not work with me so:

I want to both print logging details in `prog_log.txt` **AND** in the console, I have:

```
# Debug Settings
Import logging
#logging.disable()  #when program ready, un-indent this line to remove all logging messages
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    filename = 'prog_log.txt',
                    format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                    filemode = 'w')
logging.debug('Start of Program')
```

The above does print into the `prog_log.txt` file the logging details **but nothing on the console**..

```
In [3]: runfile('/Volumes/GoogleDrive/Mon Drive/MAC_test.py', wdir='/Volumes/GoogleDrive/Mon Drive/')
...nothing...
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [logger configuration to log to file and print to stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733552/logger-configuration-to-log-to-file-and-print-to-stdout)

Comment: @JulienSorin unfortunately, it doesn't :( I tried the question before posting this question

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of [logger configuration to log to file and print to stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733552/logger-configuration-to-log-to-file-and-print-to-stdout)

You need to add and handler to set the log to StreamHandler :

```py
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    filename = 'prog_log.txt',
                    format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                    filemode = 'w')
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
```

or

```py
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
    filemode = 'w',
    handlers=[
        logging.FileHandler('prog_log.txt'),
        logging.StreamHandler()
    ]
)
```

Comment: Thanks @Julien Sorin for your help. The first option leads somewhere when I create a logger with logger = logging.getLogger('') first. But when running multiple times, I get 'Start of Program' 'Start of Program' 'Start of Program' (multiple times displayed and unformated)..