# unformated logging prints on the console (it only prints formated to a file) / Python

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

[logger configuration to log to file and print to stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733552/logger-configuration-to-log-to-file-and-print-to-stdout) would not work with me so:

I want to both print logging details in prog_log.txt **AND** in the console, I have:

```
# Debug Settings
Import logging
#logging.disable()  #when program ready, un-indent this line to remove all logging messages
logger = logging.getLogger('')
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    filename = 'prog_log.txt',
                    format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                    filemode = 'w')
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
logging.debug('Start of Program')
```

The above does print into the prog_log.txt file the logging details properly formated **but it prints unformated logging messages multiple times as I re-run the program in the console like below**..

```
In [3]: runfile('/Volumes/GoogleDrive/Mon Drive/MAC_test.py', wdir='/Volumes/GoogleDrive/Mon Drive/')
Start of Program
Start of Program
Start of Program #after third running
```

Any help welcome ;)

Comment: This should be the answer to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13733863/13890216

Comment: Thanks @LakshikaParihar for your help, I get 'Invalid syntax (pyflex E)' on 'fileHandler.setFormatter(logFormatter)', I am using python 3.8.5

Comment: Thanks to the the question you pointed out, I added 'logging.root.handlers = []' at the beggining of the program and now it displays the logging messages, but unformated..

Comment: ok, @LakshikaParihar, the full answer is indeed in the question you mentioned! Thanks