# Redirect output of a Python file from batch

Tags: python, batch-file, output-redirect

I have the following command in batch and I want to redirect the output in console and also into a file at the same time:

```
python GeneAll.py --var VARIANT_%VAR_ASD%
```

If redirecting this Python file output in file and console is imposible, can you give me an idea how can I redirect only stderr in console and file and the stdout only in the file? Thanks!

Comment: Have considered logging https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733552/logger-configuration-to-log-to-file-and-print-to-stdout

Comment: I created a output file in Python which redirects all the prints inside of it. Now, I dont know how to make the call from batch file work in order to print the output also into the  console

Answer (score -1):

```
python GeneAll.py --var VARIANT_%VAR_ASD% | tee -a my_log.txt
```

on linux

or

```
python GeneAll.py --var VARIANT_%VAR_ASD% | tee -filepath C:\my_log.txt
```

on windows with powershell