# Executable runs differently depending on where it is launched from

Tags: python-2.7, cmd, executable

I have created a game with Python 2.7 and am having some issues with the running of it after converting it to an executable. If I change to the directory through cmd it allows me to run it with all the formatting that has been applied, as such:

[image: Working game]

If I choose to access it through simply executing the game, it seems to be reading the different entities in the class containing the colours from the backslash as a string.

[image: Not working game]

The class that is providing the information is as follows,

```
class bcolors:
    HEADER = '\033[95m'
    OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
    OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
    WARNING = '\033[93m'
    FAIL = '\033[91m'
    ENDC = '\033[0m'
```

The general code looks like this:

```
print bcolors.FAIL + ("Try combining the cd command and room you want to enter") + bcolors.END
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Windows, you may need to install [Ansicon](https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon/downloads). This link will probably be of use to you: [Colorama for Python, Not returning colored print lines on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9848889/colorama-for-python-not-returning-colored-print-lines-on-windows)