# Use colorama to change text color of Python input

Tags: python, colorama

When I try to use colorama with the python input statement, it doesn't work. This is the output I get:

```
[33mEnter the name of the AWS account you'll be working in:
```

It shows the ASCII code instead of using the color that I want. And it doesn't change color.

Here is my code:

```
from colorama import init, Fore, Back, Style
init()
input(Fore.YELLOW + "Enter the name of the AWS account you'll be working in: ")
```

Is there any way I can get this working?

I'm running my environment on Windows 10. I'd like a cross platform solution if possible as others may run this on linux.

Comment: Could it be your environment...the console you're running this in?  Maybe it doesn't support colorization via these codes.  All the colorama module does is output the right characters to be interpreted elsewhere.  Something outside of the python code has to be watching for those characters and converting the text to colored text without the codes.

Answer (score 0):

The code isn't the problem.  The code you show gives me yellow text in my console.  I'm on a Mac running iTerm as my console.  It also works in the standard Mac console.  It appears that the environment you're running this code in doesn't support colored text.  How are you running this code?

All the colorama module does is output the right characters to be interpreted by the environment, usually by the terminal app/command in which you're executing the code. Something outside of the python code has to be watching for those characters and converting the text to colored text without the codes.  It appears that your environment isn't doing that.

I think this post might address the issue.  I can't test it because I'm not on Windows:

[Colorama for Python, Not returning colored print lines on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9848889/colorama-for-python-not-returning-colored-print-lines-on-windows)

Short answer seems to be:

```
init(convert=True)
```

but someone responding to that post said this didn't work for him.  There's lots of info in the post.

This is a common problem.  The behavior is dependent on the environment.  The code is using a standard set of codes, but the environment has to support them.  There probably won't be a "works everywhere" solution because of this dependence on the runtime environment to produce color.  Python isn't rendering the text to the screen. Python can't MAKE the text be colored text.  It can only follow a set of rules that may or may not be supported by the environment.

Comment: OK yeah. I'm running this on windows 10. I've updated the OP to reflect that. Thanks.

Comment: Ok thanks. But no, unfortunately that did not work under windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in head your code

```
colorama.init(autoreset=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

That is happening because the terminal does *not have enabled* ANSI colors. However, you can easily fix this and even make extra sure it does not happen again.

If you run this on the VS Code terminal, you will notice that it **supports** ANSI colors by default.

**1.** Enabling ANSI Colors

Firstly, open the Registry Editor, or for short `regedit`. Search regedit in the Search bar or use `Run`, type regedit and press `Enter`.

When `regedit` is opened, navigate to **`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console`**.

After that, make sure you are there by seeing where you are, it should be: **`Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console`**.

Then, make a `DWORD (32-bit) Value` there.

After making it, rename it to VirtualTerminalLevel.

Right click the name and press **`Modify...`** or click it two times. After that, you should see a menu that allows you to modify the `Value` data, set it to 0. When doing that, click the **`OK`** button.

When all of that is done, close the Task Manager, open your terminal and run the file again and you should see that the ANSI colors work.

**2.** Code Changes

The code is totally fine. I recommend to do the first one, but these are to make sure and also on the documentation:

1. `init()` way

As mentioned, you can use `init()` in your code. This is not required, but you can try using it as a *quick* alternative **which isn't a fix** (first one is better).

Since that was used, we will move to the second better alternative.

2. `just_fix_windows_console()` way

For Windows, use this command if you only want ANSI escape codes to work. What it does is explained in the documentation: [here](https://pypi.org/project/colorama/).

This is a sentence from the documentation about `just_fix_windows_console()`:

In all other circumstances, it does nothing whatsoever. Basically the idea is that this makes Windows act like Unix with respect to ANSI escape handling.

**3.** Third Party Software Way

If those two did not work and you are absolutely sure you did them right, try using software like [Ansicon](https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon).