# Is it the bug for cmd terminal to print colored text by python?

Tags: python

My Microsoft cmd version is Version 10.0.16299.1331, and python is Python 3.7.0.

for below code, the color is not changed correctly and you can see the result has some bizarre characters like [.

```
from colorama import init, Fore, Back, Style
print(Fore.RED, "hello world", Fore.RESET)
```

RESULT:

```
[31m hello world [39m
```

However, if i run below first, seem all will be okay then.

> os.system('color 4') # here 4 can be 1~8

Any comments about this weird issue? is it a bug?

Comment: Please see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9848889/colorama-for-python-not-returning-colored-print-lines-on-windows) and see if it resolves the issue

Comment: thanks @hansolo, I works now. Seem I only missed 'init(convert=True)' in my code...

Answer (score -1):

use init() at the footer on your code

Comment: why would init change the output especially if called after print ?