# Colorama failed using python with cmd

Tags: python, colorama

I tried to use colorama for the first time, and it failed- I imported successfully everything that was needed, but the output was wrong.

I tried to run this code:

```
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
print(Fore.RED + 'some red text')
```

But the text that was printed looked like this, and it didn't have any color (regular cmd white):

```
[31msome red text
```

I'll be happy if you help me figure this out.
Thanks!

Comment: maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9848889/colorama-for-python-not-returning-colored-print-lines-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have forgotten (or did not know about) `colorama.init()` this is required for the colours to work.

Try the below example for yourself.

```
import colorama
from colorama import Fore,Style,Back
colorama.init()

print(Fore.RED + 'some red text')
print(Back.GREEN + 'and with a green background')
print(Style.BRIGHT + 'and in bright text')
print(Style.RESET_ALL)
print('back to normal now')
```