# Set color for text sent as input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a simple code (not using GUI or other complex stuff, just basic code) in python 3 that receives an input from the user. However, I wish the input that gets written on the console to be colored, just as if we used **colored from termcolor** for the output.

How can I achieve this in a simple way?

EDIT: (See Pic) I want 'This text' that I wrote in the console as input to be colored.

[There you have an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkaDb.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print colored text in terminal in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/how-to-print-colored-text-in-terminal-in-python)

Comment: no, it does not. I have something like: **x = input('This text') and I want to 'This text' to be colored in the console when I write it, EDIT: See initial post, I made an update

Comment: Ah, okay. On which OS?

Comment: Windows 10. Check the picture, in case there is unclear info

Comment: It would require interacting with the DOS CLI. While it is possible to change the default color via command line ( https://www.computerhope.com/color.htm ), I highly doubt you can do it from Python (it would be a serious potential security flaw)

Answer (score 0):

```
from colorama import Fore, init
init()
x = input(f"This is {Fore.GREEN}green: {Fore.RED}")
print(f"{Fore.WHITE}Back to white")
```

Comment: `This is [32mgreen: [31m
[37mBack to white` this is the output that I get. what now?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that on Windows calling `colorama.init()` is necessary.

Comment: still the same result

Comment: You've got Windows 10? See the answers to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9848889/colorama-for-python-not-returning-colored-print-lines-on-windows

Comment: I added `convert = True` but it made no difference