# Why colored console text in Python prints out color codes in Windows?

Tags: python, printing, console, colorama

I did not managed to find similar question, if any exists Im sorry and I would be thankful for link.

Basing on [this tutorial](https://stackabuse.com/how-to-print-colored-text-in-python/) I am trying to manage to `print` with Python 3.x in console with a color. A simple example:
`print('\033[2;31;43m CHEESY')`

It should print:
[image]

But instead of this it prints out:
[image]

Same results I get when using `colorama` or other libs.

System: Windows 10, Python: 3.10

Tried already:

- `colorama`
- `init(convert=True)`
- `os.system("cls" or "clear")`
- `os.system("")`

Comment: maybe this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10487807/202168

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allright, I found a solution on [Superuser](https://superuser.com/a/1300251)

Long story short, need to enable ANSI in Windows 10:

[image]