# How can I fix the issue of not getting colored output in CMD when using colorama in Python?

Tags: python, colorama

So whenever I'm trying to make my code colored, and I go to open it via CMD I get an weird message,
and the words aren't colored.

```
"←[34mHello World"
"←[33m test 1"
```

heres the code i have so far!

```
import colorama
from colorama import Fore, Style

print(Fore.BLUE + "Hello World")

print(f"""
{Fore.YELLOW} test 1
""")
```

I tried rewriting the few lines I had, and to No avail, I expected for it to fix on its own and assumed it was an error on my part but when I search online I find nothing on the topic.

Comment: Maybe duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9848889/colorama-for-python-not-returning-colored-print-lines-on-windows

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Colorama for Python, Not returning colored print lines on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9848889/colorama-for-python-not-returning-colored-print-lines-on-windows)