# rails command line on windows, strange response like [1m[36m (2.0ms)[0m [1m

Tags: ruby-on-rails, command-line

I install Ruby on Rails by Railsinstaller
and this problem persist from then on, and I just have no idea about it....

[image][image]
Could any one tell what this is and how to deal with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are so called „escape sequences,” they color the output. The Windows terminal emulator cannot deal with them, but you can turn them off, in `application.rb` add this line:

```
config.colorize_logging = false
```

This disables colored logs and therefore the escape sequences.

Answer (score 1):

it's because you have rspec set to use color output

if you want to get rid of it, look for a file in the base directory of your app called .rspec

edit it and remove the `--color` section, then save it.

basically all those codes are instructions to the terminal to use color, this doesn't seem to work so well on Windows..

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ansicon](https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon/downloads) to enable color in the windows command shell. See [Cucumber not showing coloured output in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746647/cucumber-not-showing-coloured-output-in-windows)