# Unhandled exception at 0x3CC2BE1F in ruby.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x3CC2BE1F

Tags: cucumber, calabash-android

I ran into this problem as did others noted in the comments on the solution given to [Cucumber not showing coloured output in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746647/cucumber-not-showing-coloured-output-in-windows)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is caused by using the ansicon -i method to install ansicon, which works fine when using a command prompt to run ansicon (which is what it says it's for), but not when using windows powershell.  I fixed this by making sure the ansicon folder was located in a path with no spaces (I put it in c:\ANSICON) and adding the path to my Windows 10 system path environment variable, and restarting powershell.  I think the issue is that powershell doesn't see ansicon when it's only installed with the -i option.